# mapView to show a specific location and annotationin IOs

Tags: ios, annotations, location, android-mapview

i'd like to create a mapView that show an exact location (coordinates: latitude 45.733333° and longitude 9.133333°) adding a simple annotation with a title and a subtitle.
The ma must be static, no need to have current user location or anything else.

I'm adding the map viewer in a simple viewcontroller in a tabbed application.
I have my MapViewController files, I have them connected (i guess) to my ViewController, but I can't seem to find a tutorial to do what I need, others are very complicated, I think they do a lot more thAn what I acutally need, and I'm a beginner, so I'm having a bit of trouble.

Thanks!

Comment: pls note (ten yrs later!) this is now very easy, note the answer I put in

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
    coord.latitude = 45.733333;
    coord.longitude = 9.133333;

    MKAnnotation *ann = [[MKAnnotation alloc] initWithLocation:coord];
    [ann setTitle:@"Title"];
    [ann setSubtitle:@"Subtitle"];
    [map addAnnotation:ann];
```

Don't forget to change the variables to your variables' names.

**EDIT**

Solution:

Create a class AddressAnnotation and paste this code:

AddressAnnotation.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface AddressAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D _coordinate;
    NSString *_title;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c;

@end
```

AddressAnnotation.m

```
#import "AddressAnnotation.h"

@implementation AddressAnnotation

- (NSString *)subtitle{
    return nil;
}

- (NSString *)title{
    return _title;
}

- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate{
    return _coordinate;
}

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c{
    _coordinate = c;
    return self;
}

@end
```

Now, here is a class that handle the map and create the annotation:

MapViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

- (IBAction)changeMapType:(UISegmentedControl *)control;

@end
```

MapViewController.m

```
#import "MapViewController.h"
#import "AddressAnnotation.h"

@interface MapViewController ()

@end

@implementation MapViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    CLLocationCoordinate2D  location;
    location.latitude = -15.830731; // change to your coordinate latitude
    location.longitude = -47.8753; // change to your coordinate longitude

    AddressAnnotation *addAnnotation = [[AddressAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:location];
    addAnnotation.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title for you annotation"];

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = 0.002;     // 0.0 is min value u van provide for zooming
    span.longitudeDelta= 0.002;

    region.span=span;
    region.center =location;     // to locate to the center
    [_mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];
    [_mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
    [_mapView regionThatFits:region];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid I need a more specific explanation. Can I have the code you'll put in .h and .m files? I'd like to make sure I did all the rest of the code right (I used different tutorials and I'm afraid I messed up a little). Thanks!

Comment: Here's my empty code, as it is as I created my controllers.
[link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1074257/code_initial.txt)

Comment: You have to add a MKMapView to your view. Have you done that?

Comment: if needed i can provide more info

Comment: It would be great to post the class where you treat map stuff

Comment: Look at the link I posted before, it's the MapViewController class, thanks! :)

Comment: In fact you've just created a class that will manage a map, but you don't have a map yet. Take a look at this tutorial! It will help you to create a ViewController with a map http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Apple_Maps_on_the_iPhone_with_MapKit_and_the_MKMapView_Class

Comment: I haven't actually, but I've just been able to see your last comment, I'll try and let you know! Thanks! :)

Comment: I don't think it's working, and it does a lot of things I don't need, I guess, which makes it even more complicated for me. I just need a simple map that opens to a specified address, with an annotation. I don't need interaction, zoom, etc.

Comment: I added the solution in my answer. It provides a solution for you.

Comment: maybe i do something wrong in the viewController? I simply added a new ViewController, connected it to the tab controller, chanced its class to MapViewController and added a MapView inside.

Comment: i get these errors [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1074257/Schermata%202013-03-26%20alle%2020.05.04.png)

Answer (score 3):

## 2020 solution...

> "I'd like to create a mapView that show an exact location (coordinates: latitude 45.733333° and longitude 9.133333°) adding a simple annotation...

So ...

```
@IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!

func demoMap() {
    var c = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    c.latitude = 45.733333
    c.longitude = 9.133333
    
    let a = MKPointAnnotation()
    a.coordinate = c
    a.title = "Steve"
    map.addAnnotation(a)
}
```

Simply add a MKMapView in storyboard.  Use constraints like any other view to position/size it. Drag the IBOutlet link to "map".